# Pass data from listview to main activity

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a main activity included the button and textview. When I click the button, it will display a listview and fill some data into that listview. In the listview, I click a item, I want to send the item data to textview in main activity. However, it has crash. I have no idea to find the problem and log (does not show). Could you look at my code and provide me the solution?

MainActivity

```
btnManage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnManage);
btnManage.setText(manageLabel);
btnManage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListViewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("List_data", "Hello");
        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

In ListViewActivity I have

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String data_String= bundle.getString("List_data");
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
data.add(data_String);
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, data);    
// Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.
mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter ); 
//Click one item
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
      long id) {

String  data_send    = (String) mainListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Data_Send", data_send);
startActivity(intent);
 }
```

In the onCreate function in MainActivity, I have

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String data_activity =bundle.getString("Data_Send");
```

The Manifest file

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ListViewActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    />
```

Comment: Where is your log? if your log is not showing you should clear Logcat or restart your android studio. you have to view logs to get better understanding where your problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ListViewActivity you are trying to start MainActivity which is already started hence the error.

You need to finish ListViewActivity acivity so it just goes back to the previous activity which is the MainActivity and pass data

in ListViewActivity you finish the activity and pass data back like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("Data_Send", data_send);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

in MainActivity you start the ListViewActivity like this

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListViewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("List_data", "Hello");
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

also in MainActivity you need to get data back from the ListViewActivity so  you add

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String data = data.getStringExtra("Data_Send");

              // do whatever with data string
}}};
```

The `if (requestCode == 1) {` is the number id you give when you start an activity with `startActivityForResult(i, 1);`. If you want to do the same with another activity you can do `startActivityForResult(i, 2);` and to get back data you check for id `2` `if (requestCode == 2) {  ...`

Comment: Do I need kill/delete MainAcitivity when I switch to ListViewActivity ?

Comment: @ user3051460 -- No. i think killing the main Activity will kill the App.

Comment: Yes, I see... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

1. after clicking and list item if you want to finish the list activity then you can do one thing. you can start the ListActivity using `startActivityForResult`. then when the list item is clicked then you can send result to the main activity.

to know more about it you can check [the doc](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

2. if you dont want to finish the List activity immediately after list item click then you can do some other things. 
   a. you can send a broadcast to the main activity and receive the broadcast.
   b. as your mainactivity's text view will show only one item then you can store the item in a public variable

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look [at the following guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) which outlines how to start an activity, and then wait for a result.

The problem with the way you are currently doing is that the "back stack" has 2 references to the main activity - i.e. hitting back will take you to the list activity, then to main activity again.

The advantage of using `startActivityForResult()` allows you to separate out the logic of creating the `MainActivity`, and handling the result of the `ListViewActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use startActivityForResult for this purpose.
When you call Activity.startActivityForResult(), you set the requestCode. Later, this request code is needed by onActivityResult() in order to determine what Activity is sending data to it. We don't need to supply requestCode again on setResult() because the requestCode is carried along.

The data is intent data returned from launched intent. We usually use this data when we set extras on the called intent.

Consider this example:

CALL SECOND ACTIVITY

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CheckActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE_CHECK);
```

ON SECOND ACTIVITY, SET INTENT RESULT

```
getIntent().putExtra("TADA", "bla bla bla");
setResult(RESULT_OK, getIntent());
finish();
```

BACK TO FIRST ACTIVITY, ONACTIVITYRESULT()

```
if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CHECK && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
    text1.setText(data.getExtras().getString("TADA") );
}
```

There you go. You should now understand what is Intent data and how to set and fetch the value.